# export search results to csv file after displaying it in browser

Tags: python, django, csv, download, export

I have tried to solve this problem for a week now and couldn't find a suitable solution.
I have a search bar to input gene ids (alternatively upload afile). It then queries the database and returns interactions between these genes. We display those interactions in a matrix on the html page. (I basically return a python array).

Now I want to include an export button to download the matrix / table in a csv or text file so the user can manipulate it for further research.

How can I do this without saving every query result in a file?
Because after returning the matrix, the python script (views.py) has run and the gene ids are gone.

Can it be done with jQuery?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: How long does it take for the view to return for the search?

Comment: it's really quick for few ids and 1-2min for large files

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do about this, because http request/response is stateless, there's no way for your record the result without using external cache. Even if you have cache, if 1000 users download csv at the same time your cache would suffer. You best bet is to optimize the view function so it returns the result faster. Then your download csv function would call the view again to apply the same logic but return csv.

Comment: okay but here is my problem: how can the download csv function call the view again? where do I get the request from? I don't want the user to enter the gene ids again.

Comment: You are using `GET` method to extract the user input right?

Comment: yes I use GET to extract the user input (gene ids) and then do some database querying and return the results in an html table

Answer (score 0):

You only need to provide a link that contains current url plus a flag to indicate that it's a download csv request not a render page request:

```
def return_result(request):
    # your original query
    query = request.GET.get('id', None)
    if query:
        results = Model.objects.filter(field=query)

    response = request.GET.get('download', None)
    if response == 'csv':
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'
        # create a csv
        return response
    else:
        context = {'results': results}
        return render(request, 'results.html', context)
```

In your page you create a link to download csv, `{{ request.get_full_path }}` is to get current url from request:

```
<a href="{{ request.get_full_path }}&download=csv">Download as CSV</a>
```

Comment: thank you. I tried this and it gives me an empty file with this code
`if response == 'csv':
                       response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
                        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="results.csv"'
                        writer=csv.writer(response)
                        writer.writerow(['this','is','the','first','row'])
                        writer.writerow(['1','2','3','4','5'])
                        return response
`

Comment: I looked at the django documentation and I really don't understand why I get an empty csv file when I use the exact same code that is used there?

Comment: okay I fixed it by moving it to a seperate function. I don@t know why it didn't work though.